# How to access Element created by javascript document.createElement function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm creating a div at run-time using `java-script` `document.createElement` function.And now i need to execute another function on scrolling of dynamic created div.And also need to catch key-down event of div.
Can any one tell me how can i achieve this.

Comment: If you share the code, it would be much easier to help. The answer is contingent on factors such as: have you inserted the element into the DOM? Have you given it an ID? Etc.

Comment: Yes i have given an id to that div and also stored this id in an hidden field.And now i am able to call a function on scrolling of div.But i am not able to access this div using `document.getElementById(ID of div)`.Can you tell me is there any way to access newly create div by using his id.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, check out the working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the dynamically created div into the DOM. Without doing that, you cannot retrieve it by using `document.getElementById`.  You can insert your dynamically created `div` into the element by calling a function like `appendChild` or `insertBefore`, described here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

After you find an appropriate place to insert your div into the DOM, you should be able to retrieve it from anywhere by calling `document.getElementById("myDivId");`. You'll also need to give that created div an id after creation, if you haven't already done so. The entire thing would look something like:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.id = "myDivID"; //Give it some ID
var divsParent = document.getElementById("dynamicDivsParentElementID"); //get the element where you want to insert the div into
divsParent.appendChild(myDiv);
var retrievedDynamicDiv = document.getElementById('myDivID');
```

Check it out working on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnPUF/

Comment: Yes it's working if we use `document.getElementById('myDivID').scrollTop` inside the function where we create an appent div as child to DOM.But it's not working when we call this from another function.

Comment: I've answered your question.  To prove that retrieving that div from another function works, I made another JSFiddle. It adds your div to the DOM on document load. Then later when you click the button, it alerts the ID by retrieving from the DOM. Check it out! http://jsfiddle.net/qnPUF/1/ This has answered your question of how to retrieve an element created by createElement. If you still have an issue, it's somewhere else and you may want to ask another question.

Comment: Sorry i have some issues in my script.
Your answer is working very fine.Now my problem is solved.
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling the scrolling function after the div element is created.  Make sure the function is called after the createElement

Comment: Thanks it's working.Calling function after div element created.
But is there any way to access this div (using id) from any other function.